# Multiprocessing of CSV chunks in Python using Pool

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pool, chunks

I'm trying to process a very large CSV file (.gz files of around 6 GB) on a VM, and to speed things up I'm looking into various multiprocessing tools. I'm pretty new to this so I'm learning as I go but so far what I got from a day of research is that pool works great for CPU reliant tasks.

I'm processing a very large CSV by dividing it into chunks of set size, and processing those chunks individually. The goal is to be able to process these chunks in parallel, but without needing to first create a list of dataframes with all the chunks in it, as that would take a really long time in itself. Chunk processing is almost entirely pandas based (not sure if that's relevant) so I can't use dask. One of the processing functions then writes my results to an outfile. Ideally I would like to preserve the order of the results, but if I can't do that I can try to work around it later. Here's what I got so far:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   parser = parse()
   args = parser.parse_args()
   
   a = Analysis( vars( args ) )
   
   attributes = vars( a )
   
   count = 0
   pool = mp.Pool( processes = mp.cpu_count() )
   
   for achunk in pd.read_csv( a.File,
                              compression      = 'gzip',
                              names            =  inputHeader,
                              chunksize        =  simsize,
                              skipinitialspace =  True,
                              header           =  None
                              ):
       pool.apply_async( a.beginProcessChunk( achunk,
                                              start_time,
                                              count
                                              )
                         )
       count += 1
```

This ultimately takes the same amount of time as running it serially (tested on a small file), and it actually takes a tiny bit longer. I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong but I'm assuming that putting the pool function inside a loop won't make the loop process in parallel. I'm really new to this so maybe I'm just missing something trivial, so I'm sorry in advance for that. Could anyone give me some advice on this and/or tell me how exactly I can make this work?

Comment: Welcome. Would you mind to present the output from the actual VM's `hwloc`'s `lstopo` - showing its NUMA characteristics & RAM size & O/S -type? All that matters if performance is in your focus.

Comment: im running this script in pycharm for testing, but for this processes i get:
67.95654296875 cpu
total time: 19.503798007965088
using psutill
and for serial processing i get:
66.925048828125 cpu
total time: 14.44938611984253. The average difference between times is normally max 1 sec, I do have a lot of programs running in the background right now

Comment: You have no control over the order in which submitted tasks complete and therefore the order in which your worker function, `a.beginProcessChunk`, will write out its results. The solution is to have this function return its result back to the main process where you can process results in submission order. Consider doing `for df in pool.imap(a.beinProcessChunk, pd.read_csv(a.File, ...)`. But will it actually be more performant than serial processing? We don't know enough about your worker function to answer that question. There is overhead in multiprocessing you would not otherwise have.